# Rails Spree changing default_locale only work partially

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, spree, rails-i18n

At first I tried to change the locale to `:th`. Then I change it back and part of the website remains `:th`, while some part change back to `:en`.

I change the default locale in config/application.rb with the code below:

```
 config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

I have not done anything else apart from changing the `application.rb`.

**Setup:**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'spree', '3.0.3'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'master' # For 4.x
```

[image]

Comment: Which language do you want finally English?

Comment: I want it to be one language or the other, not a mixture of both

Comment: Comment out  `config.i18n.default_locale = :en` in application.rb and also remove the 2 gems -  `gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n', branch: '3-0-stable'`
`gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'master' # For 4.x`. and bundle install , rails server and check

Comment: @nik after bundle install and restart the server, I got the error `translation missing: th.date.formats.default`. I check locale in the console on the page and got `:th`. Seems like it still thinks I'm on `:th`.

Comment: Man this problem is in your `config/locales` -> `en.yml` file . Find the `th` and change it to `en`.

Comment: @nik I already removed it, only `en.yml` left in that directory.

Comment: Reload the console before checking. Can't say until I can see the code

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the problem in this specific application, but encounter the same problem in another instance of spree(solidus) and was able to fix the issue by running `Rails.cache.clear` in the console.